# Can a typed function recursively access object properties?

Tags: typescript

Is there a good way in typescript to type a function that will recursively access object properties? Here's a hand-coded example of going two levels deep:

```js
function deepProp<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, prop1: K, prop2: keyof T[K]) {
    return obj[prop1][prop2];
}

// Example use
const obj = {
    user: {
        pets: [{
            toys: [{
                name: "Toughy",
                price: 1999
            }]
        }]
    }
} as const
deepProp(obj, "user", "pets");
```

But I'm looking for a good way to take any number of `props` in the `deepProp` function to dive down as deep as necessary. I imagine that function's signature would be something like `function deepProp(obj, ...props) {  }`. Is there a good way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Question is asking for type safety, not Javascript.

Comment: I think it's not possible because `props` should be an array (rest parameter), but each entry will have a different type: `K`, `keyof T[K]`, `keyof T[K][keyof T[K]]` and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible for arbitrary number of keys, but you can make something similar to [lodash's `get`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/bdff5c282f365e98fc95eb608b2343faba305ad9/types/lodash/common/object.d.ts#L1657) for your needs.

It also possible to use the function in a kind of recursive manner.

The example with mentioned `_.get` (its type supports up to 4 keys):

```
const obj = {
    user: {
        pets: [{
            toys: [{
                name: "Toughy",
                price: 1999
            }]
        }]
    }
} as const

const toy1 = _.get(obj, ["user", "pets", 0, "toys"]); // correct type
const toy2 = _.get(obj, ["user", "pets", 0, "toys", 0]); // any :(
const toy3 = _.get(_.get(obj, ["user", "pets", 0, "toys"]), [0]); // correct type :)
```